# Не могу разобраться с библиотекой requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Имеется такой код:

```
import requests
p = {'key1': 'samouchitel-python'}
r = requests.get('https://pythonworld.ru/', params = p)
print(r.url)
```

Я хочу, чтобы на выходе у меня было:
https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python

Но вместо этого выходит это: https://pythonworld.ru/?key1=samouchitel-python

Извините, если где-то я туплю)

Comment: просто используйте что-то вроде: `r = requests.get('https://pythonworld.ru/{}'.format('samouchitel-python')`

Comment: @MaxU, у меня есть такое задание( https://stepik.org/lesson/3378/step/1?unit=961 ) и дело в том, что нужно постоянно изменять эти параметры

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аргумент `params` используется для задания HTML параметров, идущих после знака вопроса в URL:

```
http://www.<address>.com/?key1=value1&key2=value2
#  NOTE: ---->           ^
```

Пример:

```
parms = {'q':'HTML+parameters', 'oq':'HTML parameters'}
base_url = 'http://www.google.com/search'
r = requests.get(base_url, params=parms)
```

URL:

```
In [20]: print(r.url)
http://www.google.com/search?q=HTML%2Bparameters&oq=HTML+parameters
```

---

Поэтому в вашем простом случае можно просто воспользоваться форматированием строки:

```
path = 'samouchitel-python'

r = requests.get('https://pythonworld.ru/'.format(path))
```

Comment: а можете, если Вам не трудно, предоставить пример работы с params?)

Comment: @АртёмКокин, а зачем его здесь использовать?? Можно конечно использовать грязный хак: `r = requests.get('https://pythonworld.ru/', params={'':'samouchitel-python'})`, но это выглядит уродливо. Хотя нет, данный хак тоже не будет работать - он будет использовать `https://pythonworld.ru/?=samouchitel-python` вместо `https://pythonworld.ru/samouchitel-python`

Comment: Я так подумал, что в данной ситуации можно обойтись и без метода .format. И сделать так: 
r = requests.get('https://pythonworld.ru/' + path)

Comment: @АртёмКокин, конечно, можно и так